# Python how to get ordered set with the same API as regular set?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I know from other posts on this site that (1) sets in python are not ordered but (2), in modern versions of Python a good way to get an ordered set is to use a dictionary (which now preservers key/value insertion order) with `None` values. This seems fine, but is there an easy way to get an ordered set which has the same API as a regular set? For example with a set I do

```
color_set = set()
color_set.add('red')
color_set.add('blue')
color_set.add('red')
color_set.add('yellow')
```

With a dictionary I do

```
color_set = dict()
color_set['red'] = None
color_set['blue'] = None
color_set['red'] = None
color_set['yellow'] = None
```

The syntax is different. I suppose I could do:

```
class OrderedSet(dict):
    def add(self, value)
        self[value] = None
```

But what if there are other features of `set` that I would like `OrderedSet` to have? Do I just need to maintain my own `OrderedSet` class and add features as I go? Is there a simple way to realize `OrderedSet` with the same API as `set`?

Comment: Do you explore this lib - https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/ ?

Comment: One of the [answers](/a/23225031/90527) to the [canonical question](/q/1653970/90527) lists modules than implement standard set operations and at least most of the `set` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out the ordered set library. First install it using `pip install ordered-set`.

Then you can do this,

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

color_set = OrderedSet()
color_set.add('red')
color_set.add('blue')
color_set.add('red')
color_set.add('yellow')
```

The output will be,

```
OrderedSet(['red', 'blue', 'yellow'])
```

It has the other basic functions that python sets has as well and other maintain it so you don't have to.

Comment: It seems like this suffices. Sad that it requires an additional dependency though.

Comment: yeah @Jagerber48, maybe theyll add it to the library one day, if my answer helped please mark it with the tick.